# Anvil, extra lines thingies

Tags: modeling

[image]

As you can see at the bottom of the anvil are a little bit more shape down there, I am sorry I forget what you call them, but if some one could help me and get rid of them, that would be nice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

(Left)

If you have a bottom face which is a large Ngon with a concave edge, Catmull-Clark subdivision will cut the corner,even if the face has holding loops on its perimeter.

(Right)

You need to give the subdivision convex faces to work with, preferably quads. I seem to remember Andrew's Anvil does it like this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a face that **isn't perfectly flat**.

Try selecting it and pressing Ctrl-T to triangulate it.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

The problem is the amount of Vertices, I think, but what I am trying to say is that when I UV unwarp an object like this, it needs to have 4 vertices for each face and this is more than four vertices per face.