# Subdivision surface modifier issue

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, subdivision-surface

I'm following [Blender guru's Anvil tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi87Dap_WOc). After using Boolean I cleaned up the extra vertices. Edge flow looks fine on my mesh.

However, when I apply a Subdivision Surface modifier my mesh becomes really messy as if something is wrong with the edge flow.

Can you guys help spot the problem?

Mesh topology:

[image]

Subdivision issue:

[image]

Comment: The question regarding the Ngon in that anvil is regulalry appearing, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87943/subdivision-surface-not-making-things-smooth-as-they-are-in-the-tutorial-i-am-fo

Comment: Or... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126765/anvil-extra-lines-thingies/126786#126786

Answer (score 4):

Even though your edge flow looks good from the side, the base of your mesh is apparently made by a single big N-gon.

Compare the subdivision of a quad base vs a n-gon base:

[image]

You should remove your base face and replace it with carefully created quadrilaterals.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

I deleted the bottom face, selected the border and capped it. I then used the Knife tool to create quads at the bottom ( i dont know how to create them automatically without having to use the Knife tool. Still having issues.

[image]

[image]