# Boolean Hammering My Anvil

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

I trying to do my second full project after finishing Chris 
Plush's Pretzel.  So I am on to Blenderguru's anvil and have I stalled.  Cutting the circular slots with a cylinder into the anvil built from a plane has been terrible.  My problem is after I finish the the boolean modifier.  Because of the model design I need to go inside of the newly cut circular semi-circle and line up the new vertical edges with the preexisting horizontal edges.  Now I have my anvil with 2 semi-circular cuts in the base with all the geometry lined up and I go to apply the Subsurface and disaster.  The bottom layer of the geometry is gathering together in the middle of the center of the 2 semi-circles.  I have tried this with a miroir, using the loopcut to divide the mesh before the modifier and after the modifier.  I have done it without a mirror and just did 2 cuts and still the same problem.Does anybody have any suggestions on what might be happening to the bottom layer of geometry?
Thanks Wayne

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Infamous Anvil... Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126789/subdivision-surface-modifier-issue and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126765/anvil-extra-lines-thingies and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=anvil

Comment: Thanks cegaton, my stupidity, with my frustration level so high I was looking for boolean post and didn't even think to look for for anvil post.  Solve the the problem!

Comment: Most common questions have already been answered. There  is a lot of information on this site (if you care to look for it).