# Anvil Random face that messes with subsurf on the base

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

Hi so I am a beginner and im modeling an anvil. When I go to face selection mode there's this random dot (shown in picture 1) and when i use subsurf it connects to that dot (shown in picture 2). Please help me Edit: I cant select the dot.

Thanks
Matt[image: Dot][image: Subsurf]

Comment: Select the dot "Vertice" in Edit Mode and press "X" to delete it.

Comment: The problem is that i cant select it

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126765/anvil-extra-lines-thingies and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87943/subdivision-surface-not-making-things-smooth-as-they-are-in-the-tutorial-i-am-fo

Comment: it must be the center of a face, maybe you have a face on the bottom of your object and you need to delete it

Comment: You are probably in "Face Select Mode" change to Vertice select Mode. Also you may have other extra Vertices in the arc above... Select them and press "X" and Dissolve vertices.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=anvil

Comment: Its fixed thanks everybody

Comment: A bit offtopic, there is going to be special tag "anvil-tutorial" on BSE here soon. Ngon at the bottom was really one of unaddressed pitfalls in the video